# Is there a way to execute two statements based on <condition> in one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-expressions

Is it possible to write a one line like this: `<statement> if <cond> else <statement>`. I don't mean something like `a = 1 if 1 else 2`.

**Example:**

I have a list `p` that in itself has lists. Let's assume I get an input `inputIter`. I would like to do the following:

```
for input in inputIter:
    if <condition>: p+=[[input]] # generate new list
    else: p[-1]+=[input] # append to latest list
```

Then I thought to myself that there has to be a way to make this a one-liner so I tried this:

```
for input in inputIter:
    p+=[[input]] if <condition> else p[-1]+=[input]
```

But this generates

```
Syntax error: invalid syntax               ^
```

(where the `=` is at). Is there a workaround? I know this may not be the best example. I know it may look a bit ugly. But in my opinion it is readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix statements into assignments, no.

Assignment is a statement (`=`, `+=`, etc.). An assignment statement contains an expression (everything to the right of the `=`), but it cannot itself be used inside of an expression. There are specific reason for this: assignments in expression lead to hard-to-find bugs. The classical example is confusing equality testing (`==`) with assignment:

```
if x = 0:
    # oops, that wasn't a test..
```

See the [Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression).

You are trying to switch between assignments within a conditional expression, and that's not allowed in Python.

Just use `if` statements; in your specific example you could perhaps use:

```
for input in inputIter:
    if <condition>: 
        p.append([]) # generate new list
    p[-1].append(input)
```

This *always* appends to the last nested list, but when `<condition>` is a new, empty list is added at the end first.